# How t solve Call to undefined method stdClass::notify()

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications

laravel notify() undefined method. how to solved it....help me..

Error is:-
Call to undefined method stdClass::notify()

My Controller Code Here:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \App\Notifications\ResetLink;
use Auth;
use App\User;
use DB;
use App\Password;
public function forgot(){

    return view('forgot');
}

public function forgotPw(Request $request){

if($user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first()){

DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
    'token' => $this->token(),
    'email' => $user->email
]);

$pr =  DB::table('password_resets')->where('email',$user->email)- >first();

$pr->notify(new ResetLink($pr));

request()->session()->flash('success', "Forgot Link Successfully Sent...");
return redirect('login');

} else {

request()->session()->flash('error', "Forgot Link Not Sent...");
return redirect('forgot');

}
}
```

My Notification Code Here:

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
```

class ResetLink extends Notification
   {
    use Queueable;

```
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    public $pr;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('Click the Button and Reset Password!')
                ->action('Password Reset', url('/reset'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
```

}

I tried to last 2 hours but No send mail in mailtrap....

Thank You Advance for Help me..

Comment: you can not call the method `notify` on `stdClass` as it doesn't have such a method, hence the error.

Comment: model not use in this error..@ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: ok..@ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: $pr->notify(new ResetLink($pr));   @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: `$pr->notify(new ResetLink($pr));`  `$pr` is the result from the DB which is a class called `stdClass` it's a really basic Core PHP class for just random Array like data.  And doesn't have that method.

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out things I saw in there that looked wrong...  Good luck!